# Maven downloading a pom and executing goals

Tags: maven, maven-3

I've been searching around but I could not find the answer.

What I want is to download a pom.xml dependency, and execute some goals (profiles) against it.

I mean:

```
pom a -> mvn clean install -Psome
donwload the pom b and execute clean package -Panother
```

This is quite easy with the `maven-exec` plugin. And I already download the `pom` with the `dependency plugin`.

But I wonder if there is a specific plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at [bootstrapping a maven project](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/examples/bootstrapping-with-pom.html) which is supported by [maven scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins).  This assumes you have the pom in an scm.

Comment: Sure, but I rather download the dependency from the artifactory. But that's is what I want to achieve. Thanks for your quick answer thou.